# C# migrating to Core, how can I retrieve a System.Text.Json.JsonNode element so I don't have to use .ToString()?

Tags: c#, jsonnode

I'm migrating code from .Net Framework to Core and without getting into the reason why I want to do this, I'll just keep it simple and focus on what I want to do.

Let's say I have a jsonString that contains "Name".  I parse the string with:

```
 JsonNode jn = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString);
```

And the get the value with:

```
string name = jn["Name"].ToString();
```

How can I override, extend, whatever so I don't have to use the .ToString() part and retrieve a JsonNode element value like:

```
string name = jn["Name"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't for a reason: `JsonNode` can represent any type of value. You need to be explicit.

**edit for clarity**: *implicit* conversion is something like

```cs
string name = jn["Name"];
```

while explicit conversion is

```cs
string name = (string)jn["Name"];
```

`JsonNode` doesn't have an [implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.op_implicit?view=net-6.0) to string conversion. But there is [an explicit one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.op_explicit?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode-op-explicit(system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode)-system-string).

Note: there is no way extend a class with an extra operator. You would need to edit the source (which is a bad idea). So what you want is not possible.

Might I suggest a more robust approach?
Define a type and deserialize that:

```cs
public record MyData(string Name);
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyData>(jsonString);
var name = data.Name;
```

Or you can try the good-old "dictionary of strings" approach.

```cs
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(jsonString);
var name = data["Name"];
```

Comment: I am explicit... In this case, I always want a string!  Dictionary won't work for nested values.

Comment: @Velocedge no, you're not. What you are doing is called "implicit", see my update.

Comment: I'll accept the "doesn't have implicit" and "no way to extend". ;-)